# iText generated PDF not shown correctly in Chrome

Tags: java, jsf, google-chrome, itext

I am using the iText library in Java to generate a pdf file. The idea is that a user fills in some information and that when the user clicks on the generate button the pdf is shown in a new tab in the browser. Now I have stumbled upon some problems doing this, which are :
- the URL does not change, so instead of /application/user.pdf I get /application/dashboard.xhtml
- I can save the pdf file in all browsers except for Chrome.

Please note that I don't want to save it on disc but simply show the pdf in the browser so the user can choose if he wants to save it.

**Here is the code that I use to generate my pdf :**

```
     public static void createPdf(User user, byte languageNumber, HttpServletResponse   response) {
Document document = new Document();
    try {
        /*    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
 new FileOutputStream("c://" + user.getUsername() + "_" + languageCode + ".pdf"));*/
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
        document.addTitle("Your CV");
        document.addSubject("This is your CV");
        document.addKeywords("CV");
        document.addAuthor(user.getUsername());
        document.open();
        document.add(
                new Paragraph(user.getPersonalInformation().getFirstname() + " " +    user.getPersonalInformation().getLastname()));
        document.close();
        // setting some response headers
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
            "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        // setting the content type
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(baos.size());
        //ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        baos.writeTo(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

**This method is behind a button on my JSF page **

```
public String exportPdf() {
    user = userService.retrieveLoginUser();
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    try {
        Object response = context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
        if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            HttpServletResponse hsr = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            PdfCreator.createPdf(user, selectLanguage, hsr);
            //Tell JSF to skip the remaining phases of the lifecycle
            context.responseComplete();
        }
        return "../" + user.getUsername() + ".pdf";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Used technologies :
- JSF 2.0
- Facelets
- iText

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Maybe it might need that you set the MIME content? "application/pdf", if I recall correctly...

Comment: have you set the content-disposition: inline ?

Answer (score 1):

The way that I have achieved this in the past is by creating a seperate Servlet to serve PDF documents directly.  In the web.xml file you would specify the servlet mapping to `*.pdf`.

What you can do then is rather than override the FacesServlet response bytes to server the PDF file you just redirect the response to `filename.pdf`, passing needed parameters in the URL.

Your PDF servlet can actually do the work of building the necessary PDF, it will open in a seperate tab and the URL will match the response redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Does chrome open the PDF and then not render it correctly? In that case, please open an issue at http://new.crbug.com and attach an example PDF file that shows the problem. Reply with the issue number here.