# Why does generated PDF display properly in Internet Explorer but not in FireFox or Chrome?

Tags: java, servlets, pdf, itext

I'm generating PDFs in Java using lowagie/iTextPDF and am having a problem displaying the output in Firefox and Chrome, but IE8 displays them fine.

Firefox and Chrome display gibberish, like this:

%PDF-1.4 %���� 2 0 obj <>stream x���1B1C��#@�0#��Tm>}Zh�nO?8���1�a��غ�y�ӓB���$��:9XC�a.�/f{���$� o�-$?Ө � ^�c�/��'E�j��}WT�/��Y< ?� �5* endstream endobj 4 0 obj <>>>/MediaBox[0 0 612 1008]/Rotate 90>> endobj 1 0 obj <> endobj 3 0 obj <> endobj 5 0 obj <> endobj 6 0 obj <> endobj xref 0 7 0000000000 65535 f 0000000379 00000 n 0000000015 00000 n 0000000467 00000 n 0000000211 00000 n 0000000530 00000 n 0000000575 00000 n trailer <]/Info 6 0 R/Size 7>> startxref 697 %%EOF

Here's part of the servlet code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();                      
Document reportPDFDocument = (Document)generateReport(request,conn,baos);             
PdfWriter.getInstance(reportPDFDocument, baos);
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");       
response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename=PrintedSchedule.pdf");
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(out);
out.flush();
```

I've already tried updating Firefox, updating the PDF plugin, and making sure it was set to use Adobe's PDF viewer instead of Firefox's viewer.

As a test, I changed this line:

From:

```
 response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename=PrintedSchedule.pdf");
```

To:

```
 response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=PrintedSchedule.pdf");
```

Internet Explorer seems to recognize that it's a PDF that's being downloaded. I get a popup window in IE that says:

**Do you want to open or save this file:**

Name: PrintedSchedule.pdf
Type: ADobe Acrobat Document

But FireFox thinks it's an 'htm' document, and gives this:

You have chosen to open:

PrintedSchedule.pdf
which is a: HTML Document

In Firefox I then choose Adobe Reader to open it with, and it works OK. But In the title bar I noticed that it appended '.htm' to the end of the file name.

Could this be a clue as to the problem?  If so, how can I force Firefox to recognize it as a PDF?  The users want the PDF to display in the browser, not in a popup window, and they don't want to have to download the PDF files separately.

Comment: Please feel free to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089904/itext-generated-pdf-not-shown-correctly-in-chrome

Comment: Do you have any live examples of this issue you can link to? If both firefox and chrome don't think it's a PDF then I'm guessing there's something wrong with the headers.

Comment: I don't have any examples that are public, unfortunately.  Also, I tried changing my servlet code to match the following linked articular exactly, and it did not work.  http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=173

Comment: Since your code matches the example from itextpdf.com, could you update the question code to match what you have?

Answer (score 2):

Per http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=173 you are forgetting to set content length, try adding `response.setContentLength(baos.size());` before `ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();`

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it didn't work.  I even changed my servlet code to match exactly with the link you posted, and it still didn't work.

Comment: also, try to clear the cache (from invalid entries generated in previous steps)

Comment: Yes, that link does work in Firefox and Chrome. Also, I did try clearing the cache (and stopping/restarting the server instance).

Comment: If that example works, then problem is not with Chrome/Firefox/iText but with how the HTTP headers are sent. Could you copy the example verbatim on your site and execute it there? P.S. Chrome/FF have network monitoring tools that will exactly tell which headers are sent.

Comment: Strangely, I've been able to make it work in Firefox and Chrome by changing the servlet call from a POST to a GET. I've hard-coded the parameter values to the URL temporarily, and I stopped submitting the original jsp (and instead I use window.open to call servlet and open PDF).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
// setting the content type
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
// the contentlength
response.setContentLength(baos.size());
// write ByteArrayOutputStream to the ServletOutputStream
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(os);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

after closing  document.close();

Answer (score -1):

I have answer for this ,I sucessed by opening .PDF file in new tab,From developemnt perspective ON CLICK either button or link target should be balnk e.g(target=_blank)