# Generate PDF as Output Stream in HTTP request in java

Tags: java, http, pdf

I am using following snippet code for Generate PDF as Output Stream in HTTP request in java 
    Code is:-

```
        webAppAccess.getHttpServletResponse().setContentType("application/pdf");

        try {
            // step 1
            Document document = new Document();
            // step 2
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, webAppAccess
                    .getHttpServletResponse().getOutputStream());
            // step 3
            document.open();
            // step 4
            document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
            document.add(new Paragraph(new Date().toString()));
            // step 5
            document.close();
        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            throw new IOException(de.getMessage());
        }
```

I am getting pdf on screen

> %PDF-1.4 %���� 2 0 obj <>stream x�+�r
>   �26S�00SI�2P�5�1���BҸ4>>>/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Parent 3 0 R/Contents
>   2 0 R/Type/Page>> endobj 1 0 obj <> endobj 3 0 obj <> endobj 5 0 obj
>   <> endobj 6 0 obj <> endobj xref 0 7 0000000000 65535 f 0000000331
>   00000 n 0000000015 00000 n 0000000419 00000 n 0000000174 00000 n
>   0000000470 00000 n 0000000515 00000 n trailer <]/Info 6 0 R>>
>   %iText-5.4.0 startxref 668 %%EOF

Please help me out for the same

Comment: you need to set up the content-type header. The data you're getting back is the PDF, but the browser doesn't know it's a PDF.

Comment: what piece of code should i add for that? could you please give me..

Answer (score 2):

You might want to add one header where you mention response is an attachment ->

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + pdfFileName);
```

Comment: Hi Amit, what would be value of pdfFileName variable?

Comment: Name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = // make a bytearray output from the document
// setting some response headers
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.pdf");
// setting the content type
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(baos.size());
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

baos.writeTo(bos);
bos.flush(); 
bos.close();
```

Comment: thank you so much but it doesn't work still same error

Comment: are you certain that the file works properly when you're not trying to serve it through http? i.e. have you tried writing the file to disk and verified that it opens from the hd?

Comment: yes it got saved in disk(D:) but my issue is same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407156/why-does-generated-pdf-display-properly-in-internet-explorer-but-not-in-firefox

Answer (score -1):

Thank God finally it worked!!!,I sucessed by opening .PDF file in new tab,From developemnt perspective ON CLICK either button or link target should be balnk e.g(target=_blank)