# Having a trouble to open a pdf in chrome using itext library in Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

Hi everyone I have question about the iText library.

I am currently using iText 1.3 version in my web application and trying to create a PDF file. PDF is generated properly but I use a checkbox to sign the document and I customized the three buttons for save, selectAll and DeselectAll.

It works fine in IE and firefox but is not working in Chrome. Can anyone guide me why it is happening! Do I need to upgrade my iText version to latest version 7.0.4 core?

is the latest version 7.0.4 supported by all browser?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089904/itext-generated-pdf-not-shown-correctly-in-chrome

Comment: I saw this post previously but Its still not working

Comment: **a** Compatibility issues with browsers usually is not due to the pdf library you use but of the way you return its product, the pdf, to the browser. Thus, you should look at that part of your code. **b** That been said iText version 1.3 is so ancient you should update nonetheless.

Comment: Why are you asking iText for a solution to a Chrome problem? You should ask Google to solve the problem.

Comment: I upgrade iText to 5 but still its not working on Chrome browser? Is there any plugin I need to install into my browser?

Comment: As mentioned in my comment, the issue your question is about is not related to iText; considering the iText version you used, though, an update advice was necessary.

Comment: @mkl it is working in other browser (IE, Mozilla) but not in Chrome

Comment: Thus, the *obvious* thing to check is whether this is a Chrome issue or probably an issue of contradictory (i.e. at least partially false) information in web response headers you use for serving the PDF. Wondering whether this is an iText issue should only come if those options have properly investigated...

Comment: That been said, many browsers (not IE) have built-in PDF viewers, but these viewers usually only support a very limited subset of the PDF standard. If you want to use PDFs in excess of the most trivial use cases, you don't display them in a such a built-in viewer.

Answer (score 0):

This does not sound like a problem with the PDF or iText.  It sounds like it is a problem with your html/javascript for your web page.  You should say specifically what you mean by "it is not working".  Do you get an error?

I suggest you make your buttons do something very simple (alert() or console.log()) and see if that works.  You might find that fails in Chrome too which proves it is not related to the iText library.

Comment: "It is not working on Chrome" mean when I hit the button on pdf file it doesn't perform any thing not even alert or console. For creating a pdf with custom button I use iText library - JAVA. When I try to run application on different browser(IE,  Mozilla) other than Chrome, it is working as expected

Comment: Hi Humaira.  Are you saying the buttons are inside the PDF (part of the PDF content)?  Are they hyperlinks?